# What is the precedence of components' lifecycle hooks when navigating via vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I've noticed that the `created` hook of destination component occurs before `beforeDestroy` hook of the origin when navigating from origin to destination. Assume we have this router:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/foo', component: Foo },
    { path: '/bar', component: Bar }
  ],
})
```

What is the actual precedence of components' lifecycle hooks (`beforeCreate`, `created`, `beforeMount`, `mounted`, `activated`, `deactivated`, `beforeDestroy`, `destroyed`) when navigating from `/foo` to `/bar`?

And what is the full navigation flow in combination with navigation guards (`beforeRouteLeave`, `beforeEach`, `beforeRouteUpdate`, `beforeEnter` `beforeRouteEnter`, `beforeResolve`, `afterEach`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hafez/fn423ha7), Here is the precedence of lifecycle hooks when navigating from `Foo` to `Bar`:

1. `Bar`: `beforeCreate`
2. `Bar`: `created`
3. `Bar`: `beforeMount`
4. `Foo`: `beforeDestroy`
5. `Foo`: `destroyed`
6. `Bar`: `mounted`

And following is the full navigation flow:

1. Origin: `beforeRouteLeave` guard.
2. Global: `beforeEach` guard.
3. Destination: `beforeEnter` gaurd.
4. Destination: `beforeRouteEnter` guard.
5. Global: `beforeResolve` guard.
6. Global: `afterEach` guard.
7. Destination: `beforeCreate` lifecycle hook.
8. Destination: `created` lifecycle hook.
9. Destination: `beforeMount` lifecycle hook.
10. Destination: callback passed to `next` in `beforeRouteEnter` guard.
11. Origin: `beforeDestroy` lifecycle hook.
12. Origin: `destroyed` lifecycle hook.
13. Destination: `mounted` lifecycle hook.

When using `keep-alive`:

9. ...
10. Destination: callback passed to `next` in `beforeRouteEnter` guard.
11. Origin: `deactivated` lifecycle hook.
12. Destination: `mounted` lifecycle hook.
13. Destination: `activated` lifecycle hook.

Comment: You cannot see timestamps, but you can go back over the history of your fiddle, for example, `hooksMixin` was introduced in revision 5: https://jsfiddle.net/hafez/fn423ha7/5

Comment: @meagar Yes, its 43 revisions shows the process of completion, thank you for pointing that out.