# Lifecycle hooks not working properly in order After migration from vu2 to vue3

Tags: vuejs3, vue-loader

The issue is when I switch from Route 1 to Route 2 then First "**created**" of route2 being called after that "**unmounted**" of route1. Actually it should be like first "**unmounted**" of Route1 should call after that "**created**" of Route1

I am using a common store in two routes. And registering and deregistering those stores in "**created**" and "**unmounted**" in all routes.

**Route 1-**

```
created() {
this.registerStore('Store1', Store1);
}
unmounted() {
this.unregisterStore('Store1');
}
```

Here Store1 is a common store in Route2.

**Route 2 -**

```
created() {
this.registerStore('Store2', Store2);
this.registerStore('Store1', Store1);
}
unmounted() {
this.unregisterStore('Store2');
this.unregisterStore('Store1');
}
```

Now the issue is when I switch from Route 1 to Route 2 then First "**created**" of route2 being called after that "**unmounted**" of route1. So in this case My store1 first register and then unregister because of that my Page is getting error on Route2 where using Store1

So I am not able to use common store in that case and separated stores.

Answer (score 1):

It's my [observation](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-cdn-8jp48f?file=/src/components/Component1.vue) that a new component's created hook runs before an old component's unmounted hook in Vue 2, same as Vue 3, and is also backed up by this [older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66522274/6225326) on SO.

Regardless, this type of logic should be centralized so conflicts of this type can be avoided.  Something like the [beforeEnter guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard) or [beforeEach guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards) could unregister and register stores as needed based on the component you're leaving `from` and the component you're entering `to`

beforeEnter example:

```js
{
    path: '/route2',
    component: Component2,
    beforeEnter: (to, from) => {
      if (from.path === '/route1') {
        unregisterStore('Store1');
      }
      registerStore('Store2', Store2);
      registerStore('Store1', Store1);
      // accept the navigation
      return true
    },
},
```

Logic can perhaps be simplified (not sure if unregistering then re-registering immediately is necessary for your use case).